# Ajax Live Search with Multiple Inputs

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, jquery-selectors, livesearch

I am writing an ajax live search feature into my software. There are multiple input that need to be ajax searchable on each form. Everything works great except I want the list of results to be displayed in a hovering "p" element right below the input I am currently searching in. Right now I have a "p" with class = "options" right below each input to display the results. When I type, the results are displayed in EVERY "p", that is, hovering under every input. Is there a way to reference just the child of the current input or do I need to use a separate function explicitly referencing the desired

for each input? I've tried a lot of child selector options on the internet and none of them have worked. The code is below. Thank you for your advice.

```
$(document).ready(function() {

//sets the chosen value into the input
$( ".options").on( "click", function(event) {
   var item =  $(event.target).text(); 
   $('#acctname').val(item);//place chosed result into the acctname input
   $('.options').hide();//hide result options after click
}); 

//On pressing a key in input field, this function will be called.
$(".textinput").keyup(function() {
   var id = $(this).attr("id");
   var val = $(this).val();
   if (val === '') { //Validating, if "name" is empty.
   $('div > p').html('').show();
   }else {//If input is not empty.

        $.ajax({
           type: "POST",
           url: "../model/ajax/livesearch.php",
           data: {id: id, val: val},
           success: function(html) {//place the result into the p element and set the proper css
              $('div > p').html(html).show().css({"position":"absolute","z-index":"+1","cursor":"pointer","color":"black","background-color":"white"});
              }
       });
   }
});
});
```

Update: this is how my HTML forms are structured.

```
<form action= "../model/dataentry.php?formname=enter_deposit" method="POST" id="ajaxform" name="ajaxform">
<div class = "label"><p1>Revenue Account Name</p1></div><div class = "field"><input class = "textinput" type="input" name="acctname" id="acctname" value = ""  autocomplete="off">
<p class = "options"></p></div>
<div class = "label"><p1>Revenue Account Number</p1></div><div class = "field"><input class = "textinput" type="input" name="acctno" id="acctno" value = ""  autocomplete="off">
<p class = "options"></p></div>
<input class = "submit" name = "Submit" type = "button" id = "ajaxsubmit" value = "Submit"  >
<input class = "submit" name = "Close" type = "button" id = "close" value = "Close"  >
</div>
</form>
```

Comment: add your basic html structure, so we can check

Comment: Change `$('div > p')` to something more specific then.

Comment: Lawrence, can you give me an example of something more specific? That is exactly what I've had trouble determining how to adjust. To make that piece reference the right element dynamically.

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you are looking for?
https://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/

Comment: That's is essentially what I have achieved without a plugin. My trouble is getting the result to appear in the desired location.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution to the issue in case anyone is curious. By assigning each div with class "option" an id equal to its parent's id plus "_opt" (i.e. "acctname" input would have a child div with id "acctname_opt"), I can edit div ids dynamically in my functions to place the result list where I want it. Here is my new javascript code. Works flawlessly. Thanks for your help, everyone.

```
$(document).ready(function() {

//sets the chosen value into the input
$( ".options").on( "click", function(event) {
   var item =  $(event.target).text(); 
   var clickedid = $(this).attr('id'); 
   var targetid = clickedid.split('_'); //remove the '_opt' suffice to get the target id
   $('#' + targetid).val(item);//place chosed result into the acctname input
   $('.options').hide();//hide result options after click
}); 

//On pressing a key in input field, this function will be called.
$(".textinput").keyup(function() {
   var id = $(this).attr("id");
   var optid = id + '_opt'; //set the target element id
   var val = $(this).val();
   if (val === '') { //Validating, if "name" is empty.
   $('#' + optid).html('').show();
   }else {//If input is not empty.
        $.ajax({
           type: "POST",
           url: "../model/ajax/livesearch.php",
           data: {id: id, val: val},
           success: function(html) {//place the result into the p element and set the proper css
              $('#' + optid).html(html).show().css({"position":"absolute","z-index":"+1","cursor":"pointer","color":"black","background-color":"white"});
              }
       });
   }
});
});
```